# Induced gravitation action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-calculus, modified-gravity

Considering the action for induced gravity:

$$S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(\epsilon\phi^2 R-\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2+V(\phi)\right).$$

I was trying to get the metric field equations by doing the usual procedure and for the $\delta(\phi^2 \epsilon R)$ term, using the Leibniz rule twice, I got this:

$$ \delta(\phi^2\epsilon R) = [\epsilon \phi^2 R_{\mu\nu} +g_{\mu\nu}\square(\epsilon\phi^2) - \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}(\epsilon\phi^2)] \delta g^{\mu\nu} $$

Is this correct? Or do I have to do some type of chain rule for $\phi^2$ in the Leibniz rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is correct. You can aply the covariant derivatives in $\phi^2$:

$$\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\phi^2 = \nabla_{\mu}(2\phi \nabla_{\nu} \phi) = 2 \nabla_{\mu}\phi\nabla_{\nu} \phi + 2\phi\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu} \phi$$

and the same for the box term, but your calculation is correct!

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: You're welcome!