# Obtaining General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, action, modified-gravity

Considering the action given in the following post:[Induced gravitation action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590658/induced-gravitation-action)
under what conditions does GR originate from this induced gravitation model? Also, what can we say about the cosmological constant?

EDIT:
The equations I obtained  for this model are:

$$ -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} \mathfrak{L}+ \epsilon \phi ^2 R_{\mu\nu}+g_{\mu\nu} \square(\phi^2 \epsilon) -\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu(\phi^2 \epsilon)- \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi=0$$

$$ 2 \epsilon \phi R+ \frac{dV}{d \phi}+\square \phi=0$$

where $\mathfrak{L}=\left(\epsilon\phi^2 R-\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2+V(\phi)\right)$

Comment: Do you have (or a reference for) the field equations for the model?

Comment: I deduced the equations for this model (hope they are right) I will write them. I dont have any reference sorry

Comment: With the action you provided, I think the best way to analyse it is to make the standard redefinition of the fields in order to rewrite the $\phi^2$ term as either a constant or just $\phi$. If you're looking for the condition when this reproduces GR, a constant is probably more useful. This is done often in scalar-tensor theories, and the action you've provided comes up there quite a lot!

Comment: So basically if I consider $\phi$ as a constant then it should reprodce GR, correct?

Comment: that's not exactly what I was saying. In the case that $\phi \rightarrow$ constant and $V(\phi) \rightarrow$ constant, notice you still have this $2 \epsilon \phi R = 0$ equation from the field variation. This is because of the nonminimal coupling, hence the suggestion to look in the Einstein frame (which is minimally coupled). Take a look at equation (95) and (97) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2476. This does the rescaling I'm talking about for the general scalar-tensor theory.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.  To get GR seems like the only choice is $\phi = 1$ everywhere and $V(\phi) = 0$.  Were you expecting something else?

Comment: I was expecting something rather formal like @Eletie said, I thought too that we just need to get R in order to obtain Einsteins equations but probably there would be something more advanced that I dont know of, which would lead me to being wrong after all

Comment: My previous comment should've said $V(\phi) \rightarrow 0$ sorry, not constant. But anyway, setting $\phi =1$ and $V(\phi)=0$ just give the Einstein-Hilbert *action* but when finding GR as a limit of a more general theory we usually don't want to do it at the level of the action. (For general scalar tensor theory the standard procedure is to make a conformal transformation and then a field redefinition to write the action in the Einstein frame. We then say it reduces to GR for some value of the coupling constants introduced and for functions of $\phi$ approaching some limit)

Comment: (As far as I was aware) we want to begin with our modified action, and we do our variation with respect to all the dynamical variables, and then we look at GR as the limit of this theory. If we simply make $\phi$ non-dynamical in the action (i.e. before variation) then I think we're not considering the same theory anymore.

Comment: Maybe @Brick is correct that it really is that simple here, my concern was that at the level of field equations it leaves a $R=0$ constraint  (second equation) which then leads to $R_{\mu \nu} =0$. For vacuum solutions this is fine (it matches GR), but for matter solutions we'd have $\epsilon G_{\mu \nu} = \kappa T_{\mu \nu}$ and $\epsilon R= \frac{\delta S_{M}}{\delta \phi} = 0$, because the matter action $S_{M}$ isn't a function of $\phi$. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: The field $\phi$ in the equations that you have are not "matter" in the sense that GR would allow it.  The only way to get back to GR is to make a trivial choice of $\phi$ that essentially eliminates it from the equations.  You're correct that from there you $T_{ab} = 0$, so the vacuum equations.  That's because you started with an alternative theory that also had $T_{ab} = 0$, at least up to the new field $\phi$.

Comment: What about the cosmological constant? What do we do with it?

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh For the cosmological constant it'd just come from the potential, i.e. $V(\phi) \rightarrow const$.